# Test if specific xml string exists in a file

Tags: string, bash, file, parsing, grep

I would like to test if the xml header exists in a specified file.

I am using something like :

```
FILE=${1}
PATTERN="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
if grep -Fxq ${PATTERN} ${FILE}
then
    echo "already exists"
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

But it returns :

```
grep: version="1.0": No such file or directory
grep: encoding="UTF-8": No such file or directory
grep: standalone="no"?>: No such file or directory
not exists
```

However, the PATTERN already exists in the file. Basically I just would like not create a new PATTERN line if it already exists in the specified file.

Comment: Enclose `${PATTERN}` between double quotes: "${PATTERN}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose `${PATTERN}` between double quotes: `"${PATTERN}"`

The following should work:

```
FILE=${1}
PATTERN="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
if grep -Fxq "${PATTERN}" ${FILE}
then
    echo "already exists"
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

---

What is happening without quote, is that the if command is expanded to `grep -Fxq <?xml version....` and so `version`, and the other part are interpreted as argument, so grep will search for the corresponding file, which of course does not exist